# "the adaptation adheres the novel"

Tags: verbs

*This new television adaptation from the BBC production adheres A. Christie's novel.*

I would like ask whether the verb "adhere" is suitable into the context of my sentence. I want to express that the adaptaion is accurate and that the authors of TV version did not make significant changes that would modify the plot or characters of the original novel.

Comment: If you want to use *adheres*, you'll want to use *adheres to*. Another expression that comes to my mind is *is faithful to*.

Comment: As Damkerng has stated, you need *adhere to* if there is an object for adhere. Meanwhile, your sentence is not quite clear. What does 'the BBC production' refer to?

Comment: Is it really unclear? I meant it that the adaptation comes from the BBC, that it is a product of this public service broadcaster. I thought that it is possible to express that using "BBC production".

Comment: I understand what you mean, but we would normally say that the BBC production *is* the new television adaptation.  The adaptation isn't "from the production", it's just from the BBC.  The "production" is the work itself.

Comment: I was probably influenced by my native language in writing this sentence. We normally say it in order to distinguish the products made by commercial TV's and public TV.

Answer (score 1):

*Adhere* is a reflexive verb, meaning that it takes 1 object, but that object is often an understood "itself" or other appropriate "-self" word and also often not expressed unless emphasis is needed.

> This substance will cause the paper to adhere [itself] to the wall.

When you place a noun right after *adhere* it sounds like you are trying to specify the object of *adhere* instead of the "default" of X-self.  But you are not answering the question of *where* or *what* the object is being adhered *to*, and if context doesn't provide that, then the sentence sounds incomplete.

Don't confuse this with verbs that take two objects.  *Adhere* doesn't work that way.

> She gave the ball to the dog = She gave the dog the ball (this switcharound is something you can do with verbs that take 2 objects)
>
> I adhered the tape to the paper - I adhered the paper to the tape (These sentences mean different things because *to X* is not an object but expressing a direction.)
>
> I adhered me to my studies - bad.
>
> I adhered myself to my studies = I adhered to my studies - this works because *adhere* is reflexive.